# Why order matters in this RegEx with alternation?

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

Requirements for a TextBox control were to accept the following as valid inputs:

1. A sequence of numbers.
2. Literal string 'Number of rooms'.
3. No value at all (left blank). Not specifying a value at all should allow for the RegularExpressionValidator to pass.

Following RegEx yielded the desired results (successfully validated the 3 types of inputs):

```
"Number of rooms|[0-9]*"
```

However, I couldn't come up with an explanation when a colleague asked why the following fails to validate when the string 'Number of rooms' is specified (requirement #2):

```
"[0-9]*|Number of rooms"
```

An explanation as to why the ordering of alternation matters in this case would be very insightful indeed.

UPDATE:

The second regex successfully matches the target string "Number of rooms" in console app as shown [here](http://pastebin.com/yzr6Bqcd). However, using the identical expression in aspx markup doesn't match when the input is "Number of rooms". Here's the relevant aspx markup:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox1" >
</asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
EnableClientScript="false" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textbox1" 
ValidationExpression="[0-9]*|Number of rooms" 
ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: For `A sequence of numbers.` you should use `\d+` or `[0-9]+`, not `[0-9]*` as that means **any** number of digits (including **none**).

Comment: In one case you have "Number of rooms", and in the other "Number of rows". Is that a typo?

Comment: @Oded: But then it wouldn't match the empty string as per item 3.

Comment: @MartinLiversage - It would, as an empty string is no digits at all.

Comment: Don't you need a `^` and a `$` to make this a meaningful regex?  The `[0-9]*` will match any string, otherwise, right?  (or does the validator force that the entire string matches?)

Comment: @Abhinav: pity, I thought I had found a brilliant answer ;)

Comment: @Oded: What I'm saying is that the empty string `""` does **not** match the regular expression `\d+`.

Comment: @MartinLiversage - True enough. I am just talking about the semantics of `*` vs `+`.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Trying to match any positive 1 or 2 digit number entered up to and including 50: "50|[0-4]?\d" works, while "[0-4]?\d|50" doesn't (the match fails when entering "50"). I've also tried "([0-4]?\d)|50" and "([0-4]?\d)|(50)" which didn't make any difference. This is happening in ASP.NET 4.0. I can't figure out the reason.

Comment: Making the link to recent related questions: some regex engines will match the longer string rather than the first option in an alternation. See [Use the right regex flavor!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296918/3216427) and [Regular expressions as finite state automata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57738489/3216427).

Answer (score 11):

The order matters since that is the order which the Regex engine will try to match.

Case 1: `Number of rooms|[0-9]*`

In this case the regex engine will first try to match the text "Number of room". If this fails will then try to match numbers or nothing.

Case 2: `[0-9]*|Number of rooms`:

In this case the engine will first try to match number or nothing. But nothing will *always* match. In this case it never needs to try "Number of rooms"

This is kind of like the || operator in C#. Once the left side matches the right side is ignored.

**Update:**
To answer your second question. It behaves differently with the RegularExpressionValidator because that is doing more than just checking for a match.

```
// .....
Match m = Regex.Match(controlValue, ValidationExpression);
return(m.Success && m.Index == 0 && m.Length == controlValue.Length); 
// .....
```

It is checking for a match as well as making sure the length of the match is the whole string. This rules out partial or empty matches.

Comment: Thanks. But if nothing will always match and 'it never needs to try "Number of rooms"', then why it fails to match when the string 'Number of rooms' is specified?

Comment: Since empty string will match the beginning of 'Number of rooms'. A regex with * can always match 0 things.

Comment: if the beginning of the string "Number of rooms" proves to be a 'match' for an empty string, why the RegEx fails?

Comment: It doesn't fail. It just matches the empty string. If you run this [code](http://pastebin.com/yzr6Bqcd) it will show that it does succeed.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't fail in console app but strangely enough the same regex, when specified in aspx markup, fails to match the input "Number of rooms". Please refer to the updated question.

Comment: Appreciate your prompt response and the awesome replies! Guess it was never about ordering of alternatives in regex for this particular case but more about how the RegularExpressionValidator validates.

Comment: In general, I tend to avoid using patterns that can match the empty string anywhere in an alternation; instead, I use non-empty patterns and then make the entire group optional: /[0-9]+|Number of rooms|/ or /([0-9]+|Number of rooms)?/

Answer (score 3):

The point is that the `[0-9]*` at the beginning is matching empty strings if you specify that first.
If you specify that *the whole string* should be digits, then it should work:

```
^[0-9]*$|Number of rooms
```

Unless you specify `^` and `$`, to indicate that *the whole string* must be a match, an empty string will be matched at the beginning of "Number of rooms", and at that point the second alternative will not be tried out.
I hope this answers your question in the comment, I'm not sure if it's clear...

Comment: Thanks. That works! However, even though it tries to match empty strings which with the input string 'Number of rooms' isn't the case, why it doesn't try the other alternative?

Comment: It seems to be an asp.net specific issue that seems to have troubled my understanding of regular expressions. Checkout of the updated question

Answer (score 3):

You probably wanted to use regex `Number of rooms|[0-9]+` or `[0-9]+|Number of rooms`, because pattern `[0-9]*` (with star) will always match at least empty string (`*` means `{0,}`, so "zero or more...").