# Greediness of strsplit and stri_extract_all_regex

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I am trying to get the `strsplit` and `stri_extract_all_regex` to work consistently. Splitting by strsplit is the desired behavior (in practice I have a long string of alternative matches that is generated dynamically by the code).

For example

```
strsplit("1234567","(23)|(234)")
[[1]]
[1] "1"   "567"
```

vs

```
stri_extract_all_regex("1234567","(23)|(234)")
[[1]]
[1] "23"
```

The desired output from extraction is

```
[[1]]
[1] "234"
```

Comment: Related: *[Why order matters in this RegEx with alternation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10248776)*

Comment: The linked duplicate doesn't mention that you are using different regex engines. `strsplit()` uses ERE (or PCRE with `perl = TRUE`) while `stringi` uses `ICU`. Order only  matters with the latter two. You can either sort your patterns by longest first with `stringi` or use base R instead of `stringi` to get the same behaviour as `strsplit`, i.e. `regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x))` will return the longer pattern regardless of the order, so `234` in this case.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question since the duplicate target does not explain the difference between `strsplit()` and `stri_extract_all_regex()`. @SamR Please convert that to an answer once this question is reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Regex engines: PCRE vs ERE vs ICU

Base R uses [Extended Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) (ERE) by default, or [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://www.pcre.org/) (PCRE) if specified with `perl = TRUE`. Conversely, the `stringi` [docs](https://stringi.gagolewski.com/weave/regular_expressions.html) state it:

> provides access to the regex engine implemented in ICU, which was inspired by Java’s `util.regex` in JDK 1.4

As noted in [Why the order matters in this regex with alternation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248776/why-order-matters-in-this-regex-with-alternation), *the order matters since that is the order which the Regex engine will try to match.* This applies to the .NET regex engine in that question, and we can see below it also applies to PCRE and ICU, but not ERE, which is why you get a different result with `strsplit()` (unless you set `perl = TRUE`).

```r
library(stringi)
x <- "1234567"
pattern <- "(23)|(234)"

# Base R (ERE) engine
regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x))  |> unlist()
# [1] "234"

# Base R (PCRE) engine
regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x, perl = TRUE))  |> unlist()
# [1] "23"

stri_extract_all_regex(x, pattern)  |> unlist()
# [1] "23"
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10248863/12545041) to that question states:

> This is kind of like the || operator in C#. Once the left side matches the right side is ignored.

So we need to switch the pattern so the preferred (i.e. longest) match is first: `pattern <- "(234)|(23)"`.

#### Arranging your pattern so the longest match is first

As your pattern is dynamically generated, you can't just hardcode the order. However, you can write a function to sort it by the longest pattern first.

```r
switch_pattern_order  <- function(pattern){
    pattern_split  <- unlist(strsplit(pattern, "|", fixed = TRUE))
    pattern_sorted  <- pattern_split[order(nchar(pattern_split), decreasing = TRUE)]
    new_pattern  <- paste(pattern_sorted, collapse = "|")
    new_pattern
}
```

This assumes the only operator is `"|"` but it can be extended if there are others.

This will now work with any of the regex engines:

```r
pattern  <- switch_pattern_order(pattern) # "(234)|(23)"
regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x))  |> unlist()
# [1] "234"

regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x, perl = TRUE))  |> unlist()
# [1] "234"

stri_extract_all_regex(x, pattern)  |> unlist()
# [1] "234"
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. This is what I opted to do while waiting for the answer (nchar sorts). However, I feel it is not the most general solution as it works only for alternative "fixed" strings (as I have in my application), but not for more general regex strings, so I was hoping someone would also have a more general solution to the problem. I take it the general solution is opting for `regmatches` (and not `perl`)?

Comment: I am also using case sensitivity "flags" `(?i)` and `(?-i)`. Is there an easy way to find out which of the engines support this?

Comment: @BBB Yes in that case I think the solution is to use the ERE engine. It seems to support case sensitivity flags as `regmatches("AABB", gregexpr("(?i)aa", "AABB")) ` returns `"AA"`. You can also do `gregexpr(pattern, x, ignore.case = TRUE)`.

Comment: Super. Thank you. I of course know about ignore.case, but this way allows to combine regex parts that are sensitive and insensitive.